# How will I join these tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I've got a problem joining these tables; I have this code.

my query :

```
SELECT partial a.{ediTransactionDetailId, poNumber},
       partial b.{edi997DetailId, noOfTrans},
       partial c.{ediTransactionId, senderId, receiverId, gsNumber, isaNumber, fileName},
       partial d.{ediDocTypeId, docType}
FROM
    MATRIXEDIBUNDLE:editransactiondetail a
    JOIN   a.edi997details b
    JOIN   b.editransaction c
    JOIN   c.edidoctype d
WHERE  c.filename LIKE :fileName
    AND    a.ponumber LIKE :poNumber
    AND    d.doctype = :docType
    AND    a.flag = 1
    AND    c.flag = 1
```

and I got this error :

> JOIN b.ediTransaction': Error: Class
>   Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Entity\EdiTransactionDetail has no association
>   named edi997Details

How can I join it?

[image: tables as follows :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not made relationship among tables, that's why you got the error here,

```
    SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
    FROM table1 JOIN table2
    ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field; // (This part is missing in your code)
```

For further study http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

Your code should look something like this,

```
SELECT  a.edi_transaction_id, a.sender_id, a.receiver_id, a.gs_number, a.isa_number, a.file_name,            
        b.edi_997_detail_id, b.no_of_trans,
        c.edi_transaction_etail_id, c.po_number,                    
        d.edi_doc_type_id, d.doc_type

FROM    (((edi_transaction a 
        left join edi_997_details b on a.edi_transaction_id = b.edi_transaction_id)
        left join edi_transaction_details c on a.edi_transaction_id = c.edi_transaction_id)
        left join edi_doc_type d on a.edi_doc_type_id = d.edi_doc_type_id)

WHERE   a.file_name like '%Your file Name%'      
        and c.po_number like '%Your file Name%'    
        and d.doc_type = 'your doc type'    
        and a.flag = 1 AND c.flag = 1;
```

Hope this will accomplish your task.

Comment: thanks, such amazing answer :) thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

Your need to learn **[JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)** sintaxis

either you need the `ON` clausule

```
FROM MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransactionDetail a 
JOIN Details b
  ON a.SomeID  = B.SomeID
```

Or you need a `CROSS JOIN`

```
FROM MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransactionDetail a 
CROSS JOIN Details b
```

Comment: , your answer was a little bit vague, can you explain it again?

Comment: `JOIN == INNER JOIN`, and yours doesnt have `ON` clausule so you either add your `ON` clausule, or change `JOIN`  to `CROSS JOIN`, and I already include the link where you can learn more about `JOIN` sintaxis.